# Error in checksum with Electron autoupdater

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have a problem with autoupdate for my app built with electron.
I hade an old electron version : 3.0.7 with an old version of Vuetify 1.0.0
In these days I had to upgrade vuetify and electron, but for compatibility reasons I had to create new project with all new dependencies and recreating my app.
My problem now is that I had an autoupdater and it worked, but now when I'm trying to build new app in new project and update the old app I get this error:

> "Error: Error: sha512 checksum mismatch, expected stringofchecksum,
> got stringdiferentchecksum"

I have checked in my package.json and the AppId is the same, productName is the same.

```
"build": {
    "productName": "myApp",
    "appId": "com.myapp.app",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "extraResources": {
      "from": "./node_modules/extra/scripts/",
      "to": "scripts",
      "filter": [
        "**/*"
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "http://myip/update/"
      }
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.icns"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis-web"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "artifactName": "${productName}-Setup.${ext}",
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": false,
      "runAfterFinish": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": false,
      "differentialPackage": true
    },
```

Is there a way for "set" checksum with electron builder on different project/folder for update my old app with new app?

**EDIT**

I have noticed that the problem is The version of Electron.
If I leave electron to version 3.x the update work perfectly.
But If i try to update electron for example to version 4.x  the update doesn't work.